# как вызвать функцию обратно после subscribe?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

Есть функция которая настраивает ajax  запрос до совершения этого запроса. Мне надо в эту функцию добавить токен, если срок токена истек-обновить токен. Но у меня функция завершается  до обновления токена, потому что там observable . Подскажите как сделать правильно?

```
 options.onBeforeSend = (x, settings) => {
      console.log(x);
      this.token = this.auth.getToken();
      if (this.token == null) {        
        this.auth.refreshToken().subscribe(resp => {
          if (resp.data) {
            this.token = resp.data.jwt;            
            console.log(resp);
            return  options.onBeforeSend(x,settings);
          } else {
            _router.navigate(['/auth']);
          }          
        })        
      }      
      if (oldOnBeforeSend) {
        oldOnBeforeSend(x, settings);
      }      
      settings.headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token,
        'PersonUniqueId': this.auth.currentUserValue.currentProfile.uniqueId
      };      
    };
```

Comment: функция типа void, и она override

Comment: вы хотите после того как выполниться `subscribe` запустить выполнение функции ?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы функция завершилась после subscribe

Comment: вы вовсе не понимаете как работает rxjs, я просто не понимаю какой смысл уже задавать 4й вопрос по этому поводу, вы можете задать 10 вопросов и на все 10 я вам отвечу - изучите основы

Comment: а я что делаю??